# Creating Menu in tkinter / Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I'm having a hard time populating a standard menu in tkinter. I keep getting a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'`.

Without the `init_menu()` method, everything works fine...seems something is off in my `self.master.config` portion, and I can't tell if it's because of the way I created my `Canvas`...

```
from tkinter import *


class GameBoard:
    """class creates an instance of a game board, creates 2D matrix, adds entrance
    & exit, and stores all of the locations and string representations"""

    def __init__(self):
        pass

class TriviaGUI(Canvas):

    def __init__(self, dimension, master=None):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master)
        Pack.config(self)
        self.master = master
        self.dimension = dimension
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=dimension, height=dimension, bg="lightskyblue1")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.init_menu()

    def init_menu(self):
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)
        self.master.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        file_menu = Menu(menu)
        file_menu.add_command(label="New")
        file_menu.add_command(label="Load")
        file_menu.add_command(label="Save")
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit")
        file_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

        help_menu = Menu(menu)
        help_menu.add_command(label="Help")
        help_menu.add_command(label="About")
        help_menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help_menu)

def start_main():
    game = GameBoard()

    root = TriviaGUI(800)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_main()
```

Comment: I think you need to make `root = Tk()` and pass it to `TriviaGUI()` as the `master` argument. I can't tell for sure because you haven't provided a runnable [mre].

Comment: Just `import`ing `GameBoard` doesn't make it runnable.

Comment: My bad, fixed..

Comment: Well, it's _more_ runnable, but doesn't produce the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'`.

Comment: If you un-hash the self.init_menu() line, it does...  I cleaned it up and unhashed.

Comment: That's much better — enough for me to tell that my original suggestion, while not wrong (you must call `Tk()` is every tkinter app), isn't enough. Will need to keep working on it… One thing I find strange is that your `Canvas` subclass has a `Canas` attribute (besides being one itself).

Comment: It is because you have the line `self.master = master`.  Remove this line.  Also you need to change `self.master.pack(...)` to `self.pack(...)` inside `init_menu()`.  Final you need to change `file_menu.add_cascade(...)` and `help_menu.add_cascade(...)` to `menu.add_cascade(...)`.

Comment: Thanks, acw --- that worked.  One other question --- any idea why some of my commands in New, Load, Save work or don't work?  I have all of these menu commands tied to individual buttons, and from the button, the commands work.  But, from the menu, only the "about" works.

Comment: Nevermind my last comment - I had a syntax conflict.